# Eloquent Join - where closure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

Is there any way to use closure for `where` in join clause in Eloquent?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
 $model = $model->leftJoin('history', function ($join) {
                $join->on('history.record_id', '=', 'work_order.work_order_id');
                $join->where('history.tablename', '=', 'test');
                $join->where('history.columnname', '=', 'column');

                $join->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('history.value_from', '=', '0')
                        ->orWhere('history.value_from', '=', '');
                });

                $join->where('history.value_to', '>', '0');
            });
```

but obviously the part:

```
$join->where(function ($q) {
     $q->where('history.value_from', '=', '0')
       ->orWhere('history.value_from', '=', '');
});
```

doesn't work because `JoinClause` doesn't support closure for where

Comment: Why do you want to use a closure there? What's the query you're trying to generate with that? Would it be a where subquery?

Comment: Or group the where statemets together like this:  `... AND (history.value_from = 0 OR history.value_from = "") ...`?

Comment: @Bogdan I would like to use something like that `SELECT * FROM work_order LEFT JOIN history ON history.record_id = work_order.work_order_id AND history.tablename = 'test' AND history.columnname = 'column' AND (history.value_from = 0 OR history_value_from = '') AND history_value_to > 0 ...` In place of  `...` (at the end) could be other joins or WHERE clause. At the moment as workaround I've created relation for this query but this way 2 queries are run instead of one

Comment: A possible (hacky) workaround is here:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4412.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is called `whereNested` and is available from the `Illumintate\Database\Query\Builder` class.

Unfortunately, the `$join` parameter passed to the join closure is of type `Illumintate\Database\Query\JoinClause` which only has 4 methods for handling where statements for the join `where`, `orWhere`, `whereNull` and `whereNotNull`.

To make this work you'll need to resort to using `DB::raw`. This should work:

```
$model = $model->leftJoin('history', function ($join) {
                $join->on('history.record_id', '=', 'work_order.work_order_id');
                $join->where('history.tablename', '=', 'test');
                $join->where('history.columnname', '=', 'column');

                $join->where(DB::raw('(`history`.`value_from` = 0 or `history`.`value_from` = "")'), '', '');

                $join->where('history.value_to', '>', '0');
            });
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working this way. I'm getting: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
2/2 QueryException in Connection.php line 614: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and `history`.`value_to` > ? where `work_order`.`work_order_id` = ? limit 1' at line 1 `. It might be a problem with binding. When I remove this `where` with `DB::raw` it's working fine. The strange thing is the query this is showed after this error looks fine.

Comment: Try using `DB::raw('')` for the second and third parameters to avoid quoting of the value which should not be used. Like this: `$join->where(DB::raw('(history.value_from = 0 or history.value_from = "")'), DB::raw(''), DB::raw(''));`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change the error. The query still cannot be run.

Comment: This is weird in all kinds of ways. I've replicated your code and ran it through a debugger. The exception here is thrown by PDO when the `prepare`  method is called. However if I setup a PDO connection manually and try the same steps: `new PDO(...)`, `prepare($query)` and `execute($bindings)`, using the exact same values built by Eloquent, it works just fine.